# Netlify deployment not working giving this error regarding dependencies , I have used Material UI and React Js for this project

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react

2:33:20 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   3 more (react-dom, react-scripts, react-transition-group)

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!
2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   1 more (@material-ui/lab)

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!
2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     1 more (@material-ui/lab)

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!
2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!
2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2:33:20 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-08-01T09_03_18_638Z-debug-0.log

2:33:20 PM: Error during NPM install

2:33:20 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

2:33:20 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site

2:33:20 PM: Finished processing build request in 8.05661984s